# What process print boot text?

Tags: boot, services

What process does print this message at boot time?

```
Starting Service foo [ OK ]
```

If I want to alter it, where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

By default this process is `upstart` which uses scripts from `/etc/init`. It can also be printed by scripts in `/etc/init.d/` (for example PostgreSQL daemon still utilize them).

Comment: init.d use lsb-base-logging.sh to output text, So it can be easily modified, but do you know a way to modify upstart process texts?

Comment: For this I think you need to search upstart sources. `apt-get source upstart`

Answer (score 1):

Some text is printed by grub, some from your Initramfs, and the rest from your upstart scripts.

What are you wanting to modify?

Comment: I want to modify upstart script text. For example, if I need to print that [ OK ] in green colour, how can I do that?

Comment: You will have to modify the upstart scripts to print in color. I have not done this, but my guess is that you would probably want to write a common file and source it. Take a look at colorizing your bash prompt.